# IBM X1 Carbon with usb-c hub with 3 HDMI monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

2 of the 3 monitors work great, it won't find the 1st one.  I'm guessing this has something to do with the laptop monitor being enabled or detected.  Anyone have a ubuntu laptop working with 3 external HDMI monitors?

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Comment: What is the model CPU and does the laptop have hybrid graphics?

Comment: Turns out the USB hub has specific constraints where you have to put 2 of the monitors in the HDMI ports and 1 in vga